# VBA send Email over proxy with credentials

Tags: vba, proxy

I have an internet proxy server that requires credentials, user and password...
When i use MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 i can set setProxyCredentials

```
Dim url, xhr
url = "https://www.example.com/"
Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
xhr.Open "GET", url, False
xhr.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xhr.setProxy 2, "proxy:8080"
xhr.setProxyCredentials "user", "password" ' <--- Here i set the proxy credentials
xhr.Send
MsgBox xhr.responseText
```

But when i use a CDO i cannot set that and throw me error...

```
Set cdomsg = CreateObject("CDO.message")
With cdomsg.Configuration.Fields
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'NTLM method
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smptserverport") = 25
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/URLGetLatestVersion") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "gmailUser"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "GmailPasswor"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/urlproxyserver") = "proxy:8080"
    .Update
    End With
    ' build email parts
    With cdomsg
    .To = "mail@gmail"
    .From = "mail@gmail"
    .Subject = "the email subject"
    .TextBody = "the full message body goes here. you may want to create a variable to hold the text"
    .Send
```

error -2147220973(80040213)

i think that is for the proxy....

Any work around?

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy you can try this:

```
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/urlproxyserver") = "proxy"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/proxyserverport") = 8080
```

Comment: I will try... but where you enter the proxy user and password?

Comment: I believe you don't have that option (proxy server requiring authentication) using CDO